# How do you add 0.1 to a setvalue?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a variable ekeys, which basically creates a ruler down a page and sets a depth (elevation) value down the ruler compared to the 0 value.

i.e. the ruler will show 1 metre depth.  If surface elevation is set to 4.2 metres, then 1 metre down the corresponding elevation will be 4.2 metres minus 1 metre - which = 3.2 metres.  For some reason it is 0.1 m out (i.e. showing 3.1 metres instead of 3.2 metres).

Is there an easy way to change this code:
setValue(eKeys[k])

to add 0.1?

i.e. .setValue(eKeys[k]+0.1) <--- this does not work (it shows a value of 30.2 instead of 3.2).

```
var rKeys = Object.keys(mergeThisRows);
  var eKeys = Object.keys(mergeThisRowsE);
  for (k = 0; k < rKeys.length; k++) {
    shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRows[rKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, DEPTH_COL + 1, 2, 1).breakApart().merge().setValue(rKeys[k]).setFontColor("black").setFontSize(6).setVerticalAlignment("top").setHorizontalAlignment("right");
    shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRows[rKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, DEPTH_COL + 1, 2, 1).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);;
    if (eKeys[k] != undefined) {
      shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRowsE[eKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, ELEVATION_COL + 1, 2, 1).breakApart().merge().setValue(eKeys[k]).setNumberFormat("0.0").setFontColor("black").setFontSize(6).setVerticalAlignment("top").setHorizontalAlignment("right");
      shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRowsE[eKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, ELEVATION_COL + 1, 2, 1).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This doesn't make sense `setValue(eKeys[k]+0.1) <--- this does not work (it shows a value of 30.2 instead of 3.2).` Please add a [mcve] including some input sample data and the corresponding expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to use the unary `+` operator to convert the string into a number:

```
setValue(+eKeys[k] + 0.2)
```

**Reference**

- [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

Comment: Wait, MDN says this is the preferred way? I've always just avoided it because it seemed like bad semantics.

Comment: I think it's okay enough for a little home brew script. ) Probably there are better solutions as well for enterprise projects.

Comment: `Number(str)` is usually what I've gone with, but if `+` is preferred, then I suppose I should be using that more.

Comment: Yes. It makes sense to use `Number()` for big projects. It's harder to overlook than the tiny `+` and easier to find, and it's verbose in good way. It's just looks a little bit redundant for a little script with obvious logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
setValue(parseInt(eKeys[k])+0.2)
-> 3.2
```

Comment: Note: `string.parseInt()` converts the string into a round number `'1.3'` --> `1`.

Comment: I think you want `parseFloat`?